# Unable to click the button in frame window. Please find below my code and give a solutions for the same

Tags: selenium

Please find below my code and give a solution for the same. thanks

if i find element using xpath, button is not click while running the program.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.goibibo.com/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Bus")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='hdr_user_signin']/span/a[1]")).click();

    // List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
    // System.out.println(list.size());
    driver.switchTo().frame(11);

    driver.findElement(By.id("id_username")).sendKeys("ayyappan.tamilvan@hcl.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("id_password")).sendKeys("tamilayya@2");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='posRel button blue large width100 fl popBtn']")).click();
```

}

HTML Code which your asking for above code:

```
<body>
<noscript><meta HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" content="0;url='https://www.goibibo.com/accounts/login/?next=/bus/&amp;iframe=1&amp;PageSpeed=noscript'" /><style><!--table,div,span,font,p{display:none} --></style><div style="display:block">Please click <a href="https://www.goibibo.com/accounts/login/?next=/bus/&amp;iframe=1&amp;PageSpeed=noscript">here</a> if you are not redirected within a few seconds.</div></noscript>
<div class="popIframe">
<h4 class="padB20">Signin to Goibibo</h4>
<form id="login-form" method="POST">
<div id="form_error"/>
<input type="hidden" value="3Tr9wJTL7Tpw0kiK5pQBBKPfC7iTcVs1" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"/>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" value="/bus/" name="next"/>
<input id="signinBtn" class="button blue large width100 fl" type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
<p class="orTxt">OR</p>
<div class="fl width100 posRel">
<div class="smallLinks">
<div class="fl width100">
</form>
</div>
<script src="//goibibo.ibcdn.com/js/v2/lib-combined-min-v2.1450940392.js" type="text/javascript"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//goibibo.ibcdn.com/js/v2/goibibo_b2b.1450939936.js"/>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show us your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Switch function is not correctly used. Look at the following:

```
iframes = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//iframe")
driver.switch_to_frame(iframes[0])
```

Assuming that you are switching to first iframe. Alternatively you can switch by name.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_name(name))
```